# How do I install Microsoft.CSharp nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Visual Studio 2022
.NET Framework 4.8

I have a 4.8 project that references Microsoft.CSharp from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.8.

After adding a NuGet package I started getting warnings:

```
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\Microsoft.CSharp.dll].
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\Microsoft.CSharp.dll".
            Microsoft.CSharp
    References which depend on or have been unified to "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
        
          Project file item includes which caused reference "path to NuGet package"
```

I have tried to add Microsoft.CSharp NuGet Package to my project and adding assemblyBinding, but the project still references Microsoft.CSharp from Reference Assemblies folder.

It looks like adding Microsoft.CSharp NuGet Package, makes no difference at all

How do I resolve this warning?